# Move object forward according to rotation

Tags: geometry

How do I make an object (like a bullet) go forward according to its rotation in vanilla nodejs (my game server language)?  For example, if an object's rotation is 0 degrees, then it goes straight up.

Comment: 0 degrees actually goes to the right

Comment: It depends; although 0 = right and continuing anti-clockwise is most popular, 0 = up and continuing clockwise is also widely used.

Comment: Yeah, but at the minute we're talking about programming language (more specifically JS) where 0 = right is standard (aka. Most big languages use that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter trigonometry!

You need to have an angle and the speed of the bullet to get a velocity vector for the bullet.

Getting a directional vector can be done the following way (v is the vector, x and y are it's components)

```
v.x := cos(angle) * speed
v.y := sin(angle) * speed
```

If you don't multiply with speed you get a vector with a length of 1 (a unit vector), which is the directional vector of the bullet

Note: if you have your angle in degrees, then you need to convert in to radians by doing `newAngle := angle / 180 * PI`

Comment: Is trigononetry better than trigonometry?

Comment: @jgallant phone keyboard

Comment: watermelon hotdog

Comment: Lol i hate it this hear i had to learn geometry yet last year I got a perfect score on geometry... >:(

Comment: @BigBenGamerGuyKSPMC Yep, you need a lot of math for game development, trigonometry, linear algebra (vectors and matrices), etc.

Comment: @balint I know algebra at least, and that helped me LOTS.  Programming is one of the reasons that math is my favorite (and best) subject :)

Comment: you mean +=, right?

Comment: No, := is the math version of =